# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rows') ------ How can I solve this problem?

Tags: node.js

I get `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rows')` error, when call `getStudents` function.

How can I solve this problem?

```
import { pool } from "../db.js";

pool.connect();

export const getStudents = (req, res) => {
  pool.query("SELECT * FROM students", (err, result) => {
    if (err) res.status(400).send(err);

    console.log(result);
    res.status(200).send(result.rows);
  });
};
```

Comment: You're probably getting an error, but you don't return in the `if(err)` branch so your program continues to try and read the `result`. Try changing the if clause to `if(err) return res...`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning your code in case of an error
Use this

```
import { pool } from "../db.js";

pool.connect();

export const getStudents = (req, res) => {
  pool.query("SELECT * FROM students", (err, result) => {
    if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);

    console.log(result);
    return res.status(200).send(result.rows);
  });
};
```

`return` and `throw` are very much required when you encounter an error